# Require directive - file url

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets

In Rails 3 (Sprocket), is there a way to load a javascript file using a url to a remote site? For example, I want something similar to this in your .js file using the **require** directive,

```
//= require http://example.com/remote_file.js
```

Comment: same question framed in CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20608119/sprockets-require-asset-over-http/23352813

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

You can only require files that are inside your application or in gems that your application depend on. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#adding-assets-to-your-gems.