# Sprockets require asset over HTTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sprockets, precompile

I would like to know if it's possible to require some assets over HTTP, eg:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require 'http://assets.domain.com/stylesheets/style.css'
*/
```

I get a Sprockets::FileNotFound error with this snippet.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Sprockets readme](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#the-require-directive) notes that `require` takes a path, and makes no reference to pulling things off HTTP.

The [JurassicCoffee](https://github.com/creamdog/JurassicCoffee) project for .NET appears to have added the ability to load files over HTTP.

[Same question but with JS...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544825/require-directive-file-url)